# Проверка существования страницы

Tags: jquery, php, javascript

Столкнулся с проблемой. Необходимо проверить, существует ли страница имея лишь её url. Страница располагается на другом домене, как лучше сделать это?

Comment: [get_headers()][1]

   [1]:http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.get-headers.php

Answer (score 1):

Вынесено из комментариев:

Если на `php`, то можно отправить `HEAD` запрос и проверить `HTTP` код статуса. Для этого можно воспользоваться функцией [get_headers()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.get-headers.php).

```
stream_context_set_default([
    'http' => [
        'method' => 'HEAD'
    ]
]);
$headers = get_headers('http://example.com', 1);
if(isset($headers[0]) && strpos($headers[0], '200 OK')) { // можно сделать проверку на разные статусы, это для примера
    // ваше действие
    echo $headers[0];
}
```

Если на `JS` то можно обратиться к своему `php` с помощью `AJAX` и получить например код ответа.

Comment: старайтесь писать более развернутые ответы

Comment: @korytoff, я увеличил количество слов в ответе аж в три раза (по сравнению с комментарием, из которого взят ответ). если вы знаете, какими ещё словами стоит дополнить ответ, сделайте это, пожалуйста. ответ я объявил общим именно с целью «чтоб никому не жалко было его улучшить».

Answer (score 0):

как вариант можете парсить страничку через file_get_contents, и если вернет false, то страницы не существует

Comment: довольно тяжелый вариант

Comment: @HappyCougar, http://php.net/manual/ru/function.file-get-contents.php - можно указать, сколько байт нужно парсить, чтобы всю страницу не заганять в память

Comment: Или же ещё можно использовать cURL для получения ответа от сервера.

Answer (score 0):

Отправьте HEAD через fsockopen/curl, и смотрите код ответа (чтоб не парсить страницу).

Comment: как по мне наилучший вариант предложил @Deonis